# Why are only five different logos available on the '/about/logos' Stack Exchange page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, logo

On https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos, there are download options for only certain logos/icons. Shouldn't this include all the ***graduated*** sites logos/icons? I think it should.

[image]

Comment: yup, there should also be a unicorn, distributing unicoins.. :D

Comment: Too many tag edits ;)

Comment: Trying to ensure the right people will see this, @Infi ;)

Comment: @Oded how so? The logos already exist, don't they? So it's matter of linking to them in one place...

Comment: @ShadowWizard - someone still needs to export to png and eps (assuming we just want those formats). I don't know how easy/handy the originals are for this. And of course, some work needs to be done to display them. I don't think that having 130 logos * 2 on a page is great UI.

Comment: @Oded fair enough. So we need lots of bacon for Jin?

Comment: @Oded only asking for graduated sites

Comment: Fair enough, @Som - but still a bunch of those...

Comment: @Sha - not sure there is enough bacon. Anywhere.

Comment: @Oded even [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/M0RZf.jpg)?! :D

Comment: @Sha - I estimate that's half a logo worth

Comment: @Oded oh wow, Jin is expensive to maintain! :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you really want them now, here's a Stack Snippet to get all the logos:

```js
var b = document.body, img = function(url) { var im = new Image(); im.src = url; return im; };
b.style.backgroundColor = '#EEE';
$.getJSON('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?pagesize=500&filter=!2*nS3FBXoeGaelFRjgff6', function(sites) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sites.items.length; ++i) {
        var s = sites.items[i];
        if (s.site_type !== 'main_site') continue;
        
        var title = document.createElement('a');
        title.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s.name + ' (' + s.api_site_parameter + ')'));
        title.href = s.site_url;
        title.style.display = 'block';
        title.style.fontSize = '20px';
        title.style.marginTop = '20px';
        b.appendChild(title);
        
        b.appendChild(img(s.logo_url));
        b.appendChild(img(s.icon_url));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can also [run it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgjzx19x/).

Comment: This doesnt seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I think that including all the sites there would make the page too long, with too many images.

What might make sense is to add a page to each site's help center with the information and download links for that site.

Also, sites will sometimes have alternate versions of the logo, which could be placed on their site-specific page. For example, [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/)'s official logo displayed on the site has the Hebrew text around the tree, but there's an alternative version with the text inside the tree that's been used in [print publications](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/chanukah-mi-yodeya?cb=1).

Comment: Interesting idea, though not sure if it's feasible. Might be more simple to stuff them all in one place.