# Please can we have all the logos?

Tags: feature-request, design, stackexchange.com, logo

On the [Logos tab](https://stackexchange.com/about/logos) of Stack Exchange, it has:

- Stack Exchange logo
- Stack Overflow logo
- Stack Overflow Careers logo
- Server Fault logo
- Super User logo

I have 3 requests:

1. They may be the highest visited sites, but they're not the only sites any more. Could we have the other sites there too? Even if they are at the bottom, in a small icon list, or in a style similar [to this](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest):

   [image]
2. As hinted above, SVG format would be really nice to have. If you don't *have* SVG (why!?) then I will be happy to make some into it - but SVG is so much more useful than PNG.
3. If you decide to keep it as it is, please remove the word logo:

   [image]

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244835/why-only-5-different-logos-available-on-about-logos-se-page

Comment: huh, @Roombatron5000 your link caused the auto comment to not appear. (it's a dupe :))

Comment: @shadow that matters less now the OP sees the dupe bar, but other users may miss it and it won't get closed...

Comment: True, well done for using the new power!