# Is there somewhere that I can get all Stack Exchange sites icons?

Tags: support, icons

I'm looking for somewhere or someway to get icons like this:

[image: Stack Overflow Icon]

I found the [*sprites*](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=82716b77df87), but it isn't exactly what I want.

**P. S:** I need the icons with *transparent background*

Comment: Have you tried looking at the question page for each site and parsing out the `link rel="shortcut icon" ... ` header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/) provides a list of all sites on the network, including their icons. These are all .PNGs, with transparent backgrounds, and all are called `apple-touch-icon.png`.

You can easily and quickly download all of these using a browser plug-in like '*Download All Images*' (for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-all-images-webextension/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-all-images/nnffbdeachhbpfapjklmpnmjcgamcdmm)).

They all have a resolution of 158 x 158 pixels, though, of which a large part is empty.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if there's a proper way, but let's use JavaScript and `wget`.

1. Go to [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites) (`https://stackexchange.com/sites`)
2. Open the JavaScript console (in dev tools), and run this. It selects all site icons, extracts the links using `.map(...)`, and then prints it with `console.log`.

   ```js
   console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("img.site-icon")).map((x) => x.src).join("\n"));
   ```
3. Copy the output into a file
4. Now, use your favorite tool to download any of those that you want. If you need them *all*, you *can* download [them all with `wget`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40986340), although I haven't checked if SE permits that. I'd *highly* suggest waiting a few seconds between requests to be nice. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771287/delays-between-requests-in-wget), for example.

Comment: It works, but I need the images without background.

Answer (score 4):

The following option is more flexible than using JavaScript and `wget` (as mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393551/422926)), but seems to omit many of the icons:

1. Go to [the Stacks Design](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/logo/) logo page
2. Download any icons you want - it includes SVGs, PNGs, and PDFs

It seems this only includes the following:

- Stack Overflow Teams a.k.a. SOfT
- Collectives on Stack Overflow<sup>tm</sup>
- Stack Overflow Talent
- Stack Overflow Advertising
- (Logos for international SO sites)
- Server Fault
- Super User (Stack Exchange site)
- Meta Stack Overflow a.k.a. MSO
- Stack Exchange a.k.a. SE

I don't know why those were picked, but if you need some product-specific ones, that might be a better option. It's certainly more *official*. See also [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244835).

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the API

There's an API endpoint `/sites`. Let's use it! Unlike the other scripted option, this gives access to high-resolution icons. I don't want to deal with paging, so we'll set `pagesize` to a big number.

Here's a JS snippet for it (assuming you have jQuery, because jQuery).

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/sites?pagesize=999', (data) => {
  console.log(data["items"].map((e) => e.high_resolution_icon_url));
});
```

Or, to get them all separated by newlines, you could do this:

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/sites?pagesize=999', (data) => {
  let icons = data["items"].map((e) => e.high_resolution_icon_url).join("\n")
  console.log(icons);
});
```

You could also replace `high_resolution_icon_url` with either `favicon_url` or `icon_url`, depending on exactly what you'd like.

Comment: Please include all the ways in one answer, it's not a poll or discussion asking for opinions, so better have all possible info in one place. (e.g. you can have the answer say "here are several ways to achieve that...")

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard I disagree. The SE network often emphasizes that multiple answers (from the same author) are completely fine (and even preferred) when they offer independent solutions (see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125752/422926), for example). The only small 'problem' I see here is that the answerer refers to the fact they offer multiple answers, which is unnecessary and noisy, as it doesn't help frame the answer.